# Get variables in datables passed by django

Tags: django, variables, datatables

I am using jquery datatables in my django app. every row in my table have a named url to another page together with the object.
`{% url 'obj_details'  obj.id  %}`. When I click on the url I am getting no reverse match found error. I have inspected the issue in detail. The url obj_details is a named url that exists in the urls.py

```
url(r'^obj/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/details$', objDetailsView.as_view(), name='obj_details')
```

datatables uses another view to get the required data it is as pasted below

```
def objdtable(request):

obj_json_tuple = list(Obj.objects.all().values_list("objnum", "ob_field", "date", "price", "field2", "seller", "id"))

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(obj_json_tuple))
```

I am displaying all fields except id in datatables without issues.

```
"columns": [
                   { "": "fields.objnum"},
                   { "": "fields.ob_field" },
                   { "": "fields.date" },
                   { "": "fields.price" },
                   { "": "fields.field2" },
                   { "": "fields.seller" },
           ]
```

How can I pass id returned by objdtable view as an argument to url obj_details? I have tried `{% url 'obj_details'  fields.id  %}` and `{% url 'obj_details'  id  %}` but bothe are giving no reverse match found errors. Then I tried in datatables

```
"data":
         {
         'bid':fields.id
         }
```

and changed the named url to the link `obj/data/details` I have also tried changing data to fields.id but nothing worked. How can I access a variable passed by django in datatables? I can use that variable in url so that the issue could be solved.

PS:On changing  url to `url(r'^/obj/(?P<pk>\d+)/details$, objDetailsView.as_view(), name='obj_details')` but its giving me the no reverse match found error as pasted below.

```
NoReverseMatch at /myapp/obj/list/Reverse for 'obj_details' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['myapp/obj/(?P<pk>\\d+)/details$']
```

The error in html template is in the line pasted below.

```
"defaultContent": "<a class='btn btn-success btn-sm' href="{% url 'obj_details' id  %} " style='color:white'> <i class='fa fa-eye fa-lg'></i> </a>"
```

Comment: Check your error, it says the variable ID is empty. Try to change the variable `id` for a number, just for testing purposes, something like `{% url 'obj_details' 1 %}`, it should work like that

Comment: `{% url 'obj_details' 1 %}` loads the page but without datatables. As per the console the issue is in the line `"defaultContent": "<a class='btn btn-success btn-sm' href="/myapp/obj/1/details "style='color:white'> <i class='fa fa-eye fa-lg'></i> </a>"` issue reported by console is `Uncaught syntax error:unexpected string`

Answer (score 0):

*Your issue is that you're trying to use a **jQuery** variable to render a **Django** URL.*

The Object JSON data is **jQuery**, so you can't use it on your `{% url 'obj_details'  id  %}` call.

When I faced an issue like that I do something like this:

```
<script>

    // Let's supose you have your jQuery ID value here
    var id = yourdict.obj.id;
    // Now you have the ID inside a jQuery variable you can do this
    // Generate an URL with an aux ID '000'
    var URL = "{% url 'obj_details'  000  %}"
    URL = URL.replace('000', id)  // Replace the aux ID with the real one

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but its still showing no reverse match found I tried changing url to `url(r'^obj/(?P<pk>\d+)/details$', ObjDetailsView.as_view(), name='obj_details'),`. Django is trying for the pattern [myapp/obj/(?P<pk>\\d+)/details$'] but failing.

Comment: Which version of django are you using ? Could you show the full error log ? Maybe the variable you are using is empty ? Update your post and add the error it gaves, usually says something like "*No URL match for the url with variables ("",)*"

Comment: I have updated the question. The variable is not getting passed to  datatables as mentioned in the question.

Comment: The variable **`id`** you have in `{% url 'obj_details' id %}` is empty. Where did you get the value for id? Try to change the variable `id` for a number, and see it's working

Comment: `obj_json_tuple = list(Obj.objects.all().values_list("objnum", "ob_field", "date", "price", "field2", "seller", "id"))` gives me id and its not empty. I have inspected using ipdb. All other variables like `{ "": "fields.objnum"}` are working fine. All I want is to get the value of id in datatable.

Comment: @cutteeth now I understand it, you're trying to use a **jQuery** variable to generate the **Django** URL. You can't do that, I edited my question with a little solution to generate the Django URL with the jQuery variable