# Using passed in variables in DataTables from Django

Tags: jquery, python, django, datatables

I know these kind of questions get [asked a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069338/get-variables-in-datables-passed-by-django), but I cannot find a good example using the newer API. Basically I am using the Django framwork and would like to populate my DataTable with a data that was generated in a view.

Within my view I have a list of dictionaries (but can easily convert this to JSON if needed). I cannot work out how to get this to be used as the data to a Datatable.

I have re-written this as a very basic example, almost pinched directly from the DataTables site and using an array of arrays rather than a dictionary - but still hitting the same issues.

If I don't pass the data into the template and instead define it directly in the javascript this works ok.

The result is an empty, non styled/formatted table (i.e the CSS etc has not worked either), however if I look at the page source I can see that the data from the view has been passed through.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I am finding this very frustrating.

My view.py:

```
def test(request):

    dataSet = [
        [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
        [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
        [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],

    ];
    return render(request, "test.html", {'dataSet' : dataSet })
```

My template (test.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    {# jQuery #}
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    {# datatables.js #}
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    {# CSS #}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css" type="text/css" />

    <title>DataTables Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <header>
      <h1>DataTables Test</h1>
   </header>

  <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#example').DataTable( {
         data: {{dataSet}},  <!-- trying to use the passed in variable-->
         columns: [
             { title: "Name" },
             { title: "Position" },
             { title: "Office" },
             { title: "Extn." },
             { title: "Start date" },
             { title: "Salary" }
           ]
        } );
     } );
  </script>
 <section>
 <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The way to pass data from Python to JS is via JSON.

Comment: Right, so that is how I started.  I passed in a JSON string using json.dumps(dataSet) within my view.  But I still get the same issue.

Comment: Ah realised my mistake.  Even though I can pass the JSON from the python view to the template.  I am not correctly parsing the JSON on the template side.  Needed to add var dataSet = JSON.parse( '{{dataSet | escapejs }}'); within the js.

Answer (score -1):

Try using data: {{dataSet|safe}}

Comment: Can you give more context? Why do you think this solves a question that had no answer in two years?